# How do I sign out of this page?

Tags: discussion

How do I sign out of this page? Usually you have to log out of accounts - I can't see a log out option.

Answer (score 6):

Click 1 and then 2 as shown on the picture.

[image]

Comment: This no longer works.  If I click on the StackExchange logo upper right I am invited to visit the StackExchange site.  On the StackExchange site, I am not logged in and can therefore not log out.

Comment: P.S. After logging out of AskUbuntu and logging back in again, the StackExchange page *does* show me as logged in.  However, I still don't find a way to log out on either the AskUbuntu page or on the StackExchange page. I consider it to be good practivce to log out of everything when I am done, even on private computers.  The best solution I have found was to use https://askubuntu.com/users/logout to log out, as recommended in an answer to the duplicate thread referenced above.  This apparently logs me out of all StackExchange sites.